# Angula.JS: checkbox array validation

Tags: angularjs, validation, checkbox

I have a set of checkboxes in a form. How can I validate the form when at least one of them is checked?

```
<div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9" ng-init="row.user_input = {}">
    <div ng-repeat="value in row.allowed_values" class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox"
               name="{{row.field}}"
               value="{{value}}"
               ng-model="row.user_input[value]"
               ng-required="{{row.mandatory_field && !someSelected(row.user_input)}}">{{value | capitalize}}
    </div>
</div>
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35899369/angularjs-validate-checkbox-array) a whole bunch of details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this working plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/5H73o70p4ONz4jxGiY4e?p=preview

```
  $scope.input={
    values: {
      'a': false,
      'b': false,
      'c': false
    }
  };
  $scope.someSelected = function(values) {
    for(var value in values) {
      if(values[value]) {
         return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
```

You can save the user input as object rather than array to check if at least one is checked.
In the view:

```
<form name="checkboxTest">
    <div ng-repeat="(key,value) in input.values">
        <input type="checkbox"
           name="checkbox"
           value="{{value}}"
           ng-model="input.values[key]"
           ng-required="!someSelected(input.values)">
        {{key}}
    </div>
    <pre>
    {{input}}
    </pre>
    <button type="submit" ng-disabled="!checkboxTest.$valid">Submit</button>
</form>
```